# Appended items should stay on hover and be away on leave

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically when someone hovers over one certain item, more items should appear (which works) but when the mouse leaves that item, the items dissapear.

However I want the "hover area" to be the whole div containing the appended items so that the user can go through all the new IMGs

JavaScript

```
$("#mood").hover(
        function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
                var img = $('<img />');
                if (imgArr[i] != "") {
                    var img = $('<img />', {
                        src: '../img/mood/' + imgArr[i],
                        class: 'mood-item',
                        name: i
                    });
                    img.appendTo($('#mood-list'));
                }
            }
        },
        function() {
            $("#mood-list img:gt(0)").remove()
        }
    );
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 control-label">Mood</label>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8" id="mood-list">
             <img src="...." id="mood"/>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use two different events since your condition is `#mood-list` div should be populated when `#mood` is hovered yet should be emptied when `#mood-list` no longer has the cursor

```
$("#mood").hover(
        function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
                var img = $('<img />');
                if (imgArr[i] != "") {
                    var img = $('<img />', {
                        src: '../img/mood/' + imgArr[i],
                        class: 'mood-item',
                        name: i
                    });
                    img.appendTo($('#mood-list'));
                }
            }
        }
    );

$('#mood-list').mouseleave(
        function() {
            $("#mood-list img:gt(0)").remove()
        });
```

**Update**

> if I hover 2 times over the first element (which causes the others to
>   appear), every item appears twice

In your case, you can check for siblings like

```
 $("#mood").hover(
            function() {
                if(!$(this).siblings().length){
                for (var i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
                    var img = $('<img />');
                    if (imgArr[i] != "") {
                        var img = $('<img />', {
                            src: '../img/mood/' + imgArr[i],
                            class: 'mood-item',
                            name: i
                        });
                        img.appendTo($('#mood-list'));
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        );
```

> Do you know what I have to change if I want to put this img into a
>   ?

Replace

```
img.appendTo($('#mood-list'));
```

with

```
var anchor = $('<a></a>');
img.appendTo(anchor);
anchor.appendTo($('#mood-list'));
```

Comment: Thanks that works now. However if I hover 2 times over the first element (which causes the others to appear), every item appears twice

Comment: @user3549524, see my updated answer and let me know if you still need help

Comment: Do you know what I have to change if I want to put this img into a <a></a>?